# Trying to execute phantomjs from php

Tags: php, phantomjs, php-phantomjs

Hello i'm having some troubles with phantomjs. Im trying execute a simple statement but im getting the same error over and over.

```
exec('../bin/phantomjs --version', $o, $r);
var_dump($r);

print_r($o);
```

im getting this:

```
int(2) Array ( [0] => ../bin/phantomjs: 1: ../bin/phantomjs: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string )
```

What gives? Im on a mac and phantomjs have 777 rights.

Answer (score 0):

It means there is a syntax error in your script, a missing **"** symbol somewhere. Check your script, for example here: http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html or in an editor with syntax validation and fix any errors found.

It's a good idea to also test PhantomJS script after changes from a console before running in any external service (like PHP).

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. Right now im not running any scripts im just doing that in a phpfile. It works when i run phantomjs --version in my console. but not through PHPs exec function.

Comment: Update: I tried to pull out my code into a seperate file and execute it with php in console and it works. When i put my code back into my documents/code directory it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Please update the answer with information on paths: where your php script is, where PhantomJS script is, what paths you put into `exec` command, and lastly, what exact error occurs.